# I am having difficulty with a ContourPlot using an implicit function

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

[image]The 2nd term results in a divide-by-0 when x=0 unless y=0 also. The curve should go to Pi/2 for x=0 but it doesn't. Running on MMA12 on Mac OS/X 64-bit (latest)

---

Help.

```
ContourPlot[
 Tan[Sqrt[(y Exp[x/2])^2 - (x/2)^2]] - (
   2 Sqrt[(y Exp[x/2])^2 - (x/2)^2])/x == 0, {x, -1, 0}, {y , 0, 4}, 
 ContourStyle -> Red]
```

Comment: I get no errors running your code in MMA 12.0 on Win10-64. This might be a case where a screenshot of your error might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, the plot works except near x=0, you'll notice the plot vanishes near x=0 for x approaching from negative x-axis towards 0. The correct answer is Pi/2

Comment: Have you tried increasing the setting of `PlotPoints`?

Comment: I tried PlotPoints->50 and a few spurious points appeared below the smooth curve but still misses the curve near x=0. Thank you though for the tip.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by J.M., use a higher value of `PlotPoints`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_] = 
  Tan[Sqrt[(y Exp[x/2])^2 - (x/2)^2]] - (2 Sqrt[(y Exp[x/2])^2 - (x/2)^2])/x;

ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 0}, {y, 0, 4},
 ContourStyle -> Red,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 Exclusions -> {f[x, y] == 0},
 ExclusionsStyle -> Blue,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 Epilog -> {Green, AbsolutePointSize[3], Point[{0, Pi/2}]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For just the `0` contour

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y],
 {x, -1, 0}, {y, 0, 4},
 Contours -> {0},
 ContourStyle -> Red,
 ContourShading -> None,
 Exclusions -> {f[x, y] == 0},
 ExclusionsStyle -> Red,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 Epilog -> {Green, AbsolutePointSize[3], Point[{0, Pi/2}]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** There are multiple solutions. The thin line is the implied zero in the gap separating the positive and negative contours.

```
pts = (Thread[{#, y /. NSolve[{f[#, y] == 0, 0 < y < 4}, y,
          WorkingPrecision -> 50]}] & /@ Range[-19/20, -1/20, 1/20]) // 
   Flatten[#, 1] &;

ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 0}, {y, 0, 4},
 Contours -> {0},
 ContourStyle -> Red,
 ContourShading -> None,
 Exclusions -> {f[x, y] == 0},
 ExclusionsStyle -> Red,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4], Green, Point[{0, Pi/2}],
   Blue, Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Beautiful.

Comment: I'd like to just see the curve and not the surrounding yellow contour lines and shading.

Comment: The curve should be given by f[x,y]==0, right?

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: Close, but the implicit equation f[x,y]==0 should have the upper line as its solution.

Comment: I was unaware of multiple solutions (upper and lower sets of blue dots). I'll try to study why, but I suppose it's due to the periodicity of the tangent. Figure 2 of W. Lee, S. Chi, P. Yeh and R. Saxena, "Theory of phase-conjugate oscillators. I", JOSA B, 7, 1411 (1990) only shows the upper solution. Also, I'm a novice at MMA, many attributes to understand for each function.

Answer (score 2):

`ContourPlot` is the usual and usually easiest way to plot an implicit equation.  But it's a rough tool and not suited to every problem.  In such cases, sometimes using `NDSolve` to integrate the differentiated equation works, as in the OP's case.  In this case there are two solution curves, one of which seems of no interest to the OP.  It is the boundary of the domain `Sqrt[(y Exp[x/2])^2 - (x/2)^2] == 0` or more simply `y == 1/2 Sqrt[E^-x x^2]`. Both the desired curve (in red) and the boundary (in plot-blue) are shown below.

```
ClearAll[implCurve];
implCurve[f_, y_, {x_, a_, b_}, {x0_, y0_}, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[ListLinePlot]] := First@ListLinePlot[
    NDSolveValue[{y'[
        x] == -Divide @@ Identity[D[f, {{x, y}}] /. y :> y[x]], 
      y[x0] == y0,
      WhenEvent[x < a + (b - a)/10^4, "StopIntegration"],
      WhenEvent[x > b - (b - a)/10^4, "StopIntegration"]},
     y, {x, a, b}],
    opts];

f[x_, y_] = 
  Tan[Sqrt[(y Exp[x/2])^2 - (x/
         2)^2]] - (2 Sqrt[(y Exp[x/2])^2 - (x/2)^2])/x;

Plot[Evaluate@    (* returns 1/2 Sqrt[E^-x x^2] *)
  Cases[f[x, y], 
   Sqrt[e_] :> 
    Return[y /. Normal@Solve[e == 0 && y > 0 && x < 0, y, Reals], 
     Cases], Infinity], {x, -1, 0}, 
 Epilog -> {Green, AbsolutePointSize[3], Point[{0, Pi/2}],
   implCurve[f[x, y], y, {x, -1, 0}, {-1/2, #}, PlotStyle -> Red] & /@
     Flatten@Values@NSolve[f[-1/2, y] == 0 && 3/2 < y < 4]},
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {0, 4}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.02], AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried you code on `MMA 12.2.0` on `Windows 10` and dosen't work ?Give me a lot of errors an only blue line.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thanks for letting me know.  Editing error.  Should work now.

Comment: One can change the range on `NSolve` to get more solutions. For instance `NSolve[f[-1/2, y] == 0 && 3/2 < y < 14]` will yield a couple more curves.

Comment: Thanks ,now  it works.